# Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT

Tags: objective-c, sigabrt

I Have Following error in the code?
Why?

**Thread 1: singnal SIGABRT**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell1 == nil) {
    cell1 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


}

cell1.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// create the parent view that will hold header Label

UIView* customView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,78)] autorelease];

// create image object
UIImage *myImage = [thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell1 addSubview:customView];

// Set up the cell...

// create the imageView with the image in it
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];

imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,78);
[customView addSubview:imageView];

cell1.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSLog(@"Hello Last");
return cell1;
}
```

Error at Line:

```
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
```

What to do?

Error message from comment:

```
TextFieldAlert[551:c07] -[__NSCFConstantString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6fd4
TextFieldAlert[551:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6fd4'
*** First throw call stack: (0x14e0022 0xeb4cd6 0x14e1cbd 0x1446ed0 0x1446cb2 0x45662e 0x2df2 0x406c54 0x4073ce 0x3f2cbd 0x4016f1 0x3aad42 0x14e1e42 0x26b5679 0x26bf579\0\ 0x14b4195 0x1418ff2 0x14178da 0x1416d84 0x1416c9b 0x36ac65 0x36c626 0x275d 0x26d5 0x1) terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Comment: What is the **entire error message** from the console?

Comment: TextFieldAlert[551:c07] -[__NSCFConstantString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6fd4
 TextFieldAlert[551:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6fd4'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x14e0022 0xeb4cd6 0x14e1cbd 0x1446ed0 0x1446cb2 0x45662e 0x2df2 0x406c54 0x4073ce 0x3f2cbd 0x4016f1 0x3aad42 0x14e1e42 0x26b5679 0x26bf579\0\ 0x14b4195 0x1418ff2 0x14178da 0x1416d84 0x1416c9b 0x36ac65 0x36c626 0x275d 0x26d5 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your are calling somewhere a (non-existing) `size` method for a string object. Probably, you are meaning `length`.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with your logic, you are referring to the same thing in different ways, you are retrieving the object living in the thumbnails `NSArray` the following two ways:

```
// Here you assume there is an image in the thumbnails array
UIImage *myImage = [thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// Here you assume there is a filename in the thumbnails array
cell1.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```